# EF Core 3.0 Reversing SQL Insert Statements when using DbSet.Add method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have recently upgraded my .NET Core Web Application from using EF Core 2.2 to using EF Core 3.0. After the upgrade, I am running into a strange issue. I want to insert a user into the database, and in order to do so I have to insert into a few different tables -

1. User table
2. User Email table
3. User Role table

I am inserting into the User table first, this way I can use the "UserId" in the "UserEmail" and "UserRole" tables. I have a repository class for each one of the tables/entities - "UserRepository", "UserRoleRepository" and "UserEmailRepository".  Each one of these repository classes inherits from a "BaseRepository".

```
public RepositoryBase(DbContext context)
{
      _context = context;
      _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}

public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
{
     _dbSet.Add(entity);
}
```

*TEntity is either "User", "UserRole" or "UserEmail"

The insert operation is done in a "UserService" which injects a "UnitOfWork" class that contains the 3 above repositories. The insert method also passes in a "UserDTO" object where all of the necessary user information needed to be inserted is located.

```
user = new User
{
     FirstName = userDTO.FirstName,
     LastName = userDTO.LastName 
};

_unitOfWork.UserRepository.Add(user);

_unitOfWork.UserRoleRepository.Add(new UserRole
{
      UserId = user.UserId,
      RoleId = role.RoleId
});

_unitOfWork.UserEmailRepository.Add(new UserEmail
{
      UserId = user.UserId,
      EmailAddress = userDTO.EmailAddress,            
});

_unitOfWork.Save();
```

- For the insert into the "UserRole" table, I already have gotten the roleId in some previous line
- The `_unitOfWork.Save()` does a `_context.SaveChanges()` in the implementation of my "UnitOfWork" class.
- I want all of these in the same transaction and I want to user the "UserId" for the "UserRole" and "UserEmail" tables.

So the issue is when the code calls `_unitOfWork.Save()` it throws a FK exception related to the "UserId". I took a look at the query which was being generated and the SQL Insert statements are in reverse order than how I called them in the code, it looks something like this -

1. "INSERT INTO User.Emails..."
2. "INSERT INTO User.Roles..."
3. "INSERT INTO User.Users..."

When it should be

1. "INSERT INTO User.Users..."
2. "INSERT INTO User.Roles..."
3. "INSERT INTO User.Emails..."

For some reason Entity Framework is generating the SQL statements in reverse order than what it should be, and because of this the "User.Roles" table and the "User.Emails" table do not have a valid "UserId" to insert.

Now, this only started happening after I upgraded from EF 2.2 to EF 3.0, it was all working before. I looked to see if this was involved in any of the breaking changes, and did not see anything that could help.

Maybe I missed some small configuration that I need, I am just not sure. Is there anything I need to add to maybe the Startup.cs file to make this work how it was before?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the issue is from what you've provided, but in general, EF employs internal change tracking which can get messed up if you do things tangentially to EF, such that it's not aware of/can't see. This is a *common* problem caused by using the repository/unit of work patterns with EF, which you should *not* be doing. EF implements these patterns already. When you opt to use EF, you are opting to use a third-party DAL. Creating your own DAL layer around it is both pointless and error-prone.

Comment: Excellent thank you for directing me to the already asked question.  I guess that is my problem since I did notice that the "UserId" wasn't a large negative number anymore it was 0.  Thank you

Comment: Also, the reason I employ the repository/unit of work pattern is so I have an abstraction between my data access layer and my business layer.  If I ever wanted to switch out entity framework for another technology one day I couldn't do that if I have entity framework implementation details in my business layer.  Thank you for directing me to the duplicated question.

Comment: The repository pattern doesn't buy you that. You still won't be able to easily switch ORMs, nor are you ever likely to without a major rewrite, anyways. Besides, alternate patterns such as CQRS, service layer, or microservices would do a better job at truly abstracting the dependency, and provide numerous other benefits to boot. The repository pattern is just wrong here